# Как убрать дрожание и "призраки" скрытых элементов при обновлении веб-страницы. Причины появления. CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, веб-сайт

имеется сайт, на вордпрессе.
Имеется страница на которой присутствуют скрытые элементы, которые выводятся при нажатии кнопок, например выпадающее меню со структурой курса или поиск.

Данные элементы дергаются, дрожат при обновлении страницы, появляются как-будто отголоски или "призраки" этих элементов, очень сильно раздражает, да и не должно быть так.

С чем это может быть связано? Посоветуйте что сделать. Уверен проблема как-то должна решаться на уровне css

[Ссылка на видео на котором это видно](https://u-intosai.org/video/1892649126856.mov)

В консоле вот такие ошибки, при обновлении кстати, что это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне кажется что js долго грузится (например оно у вас в "подвале", или очень большой файл). Поэтому пока оно прогрузится, элементы успевают отобразиться. (или аналогично с css)

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов подобного "дрожания" в Wordpress может быть результат неверно настроенного плагина кеширования.

Comment: Плагина с кэшированием нет, не использую

Comment: Также думал, что виной всему может быть настройки в htaccess, убирал строки, не дало результатов
FileETag MTime Size

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE

Comment: Также грешил на плагин SiteOrigin CSS - все стили, которые меняются, вставляются в этот плагин поверх, так как шаблон постоянно обновляется и все меняется. Пробовал отключат плагин тоже безрезультатно